# 3D polar graph using cartesian data in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, polar-coordinates

I want to have a 3D polar plot in Matlab. I have a set of cartesian coordinates at points in space and also have corresponding data to plot. 
For example, I have 200 numbers of Cartesian (x,y,z) points and 200 numbers of scalar data to be plotted. I tried using `patternCustom` in Matlab (by converting the cartesian coordinates to spherical polar ones). But it did not help.

The code I used like-
first I save the cartesian coordinates in a column then converting each point to spherical polar by

```
[az,el,r]=cart2sph(x,y,z);
patternCustom(M,el,az);
```

Can anyone please help me? thanks

Comment: What is `M`? Please, show more code so we can to reproduce it. Then also what is the error message? When you say *it did not help*, what is expected and what you have?

Comment: You have to provide at least a minimal sample of data, the tried code and the expected result (or explain why the provided code result does not match your expectations). Instead of your 200 data points, make an example with a subset of it (like 5-10 points). Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)